# how to extract Aes keys using frida script

Tags: python

```
C:\frida-master>python frida-get-AES-keys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\frida-master\frida-get-AES-keys", line 48, in <module>
    session = frida.get_usb_device().attach('com.example.a11x256.frida_test')
  File "C:\Users\Umer Farooq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\frida\__init__.py", line 89, in get_usb_device
    return get_device_matching(lambda d: d.type == 'usb', timeout, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umer Farooq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\frida\__init__.py", line 97, in get_device_matching
    return get_device_manager().get_device_matching(predicate, timeout, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umer Farooq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\frida\core.py", line 26, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umer Farooq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\frida\core.py", line 58, in get_device_matching
    return Device(self._impl.get_device_matching(lambda d: predicate(Device(d)), raw_timeout))
frida.InvalidArgumentError: device not found
```

Comment: how to solved this issue?

Comment: Looks like this script is expecting to find a usb device, which is not present.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.